# Segue in swift based on a logic

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want show a one of the two views in swift based on a if statement when the application first launches how do I do that
this is the logic

```
if signupconfirmed == true {
// have to show one view 
} else {
// have to show another view 
}
```

Comment: Your app is story board based or xibs?

Comment: its storyboard based .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is you can initiate viewController with identifier with below code:

```
var signupconfirmed = true
@IBAction func signUpPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if signupconfirmed {
        // have to show one view
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("First") as! SViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // have to show another view
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! TViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can perform this action in your `AppDelegate.swift`

Here is your code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let signupconfirmed = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("SignUp")
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var initialViewController = UIViewController()
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if signupconfirmed {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("First") as! UIViewController
    } else{
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! UIViewController
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi , there is no signup button function I the variable will have value set already based on some logic so when the user opens the application for the second time I want to show him one of the two view in the beginning of the application itself  . Here is the rough idea of  user launches app -> the app should show one of the two views based on the value that is present in signupconfirmed variable -> this should all happen everytime when user launches the app . ( the variable is stored in NSUserDefaults.standardDefaults. Thank YOu.

Comment: Like in Whatsapp , when first time the app is launched the phone number verification view is shown when its confirmed and when the user launches some other time the view is shown is users table view (the signup is never sen again )  same kinda mechanism Im looking for

Comment: Ok I understand your problem and let me update my answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

in your appDelegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" before return

```
 var userSignedUp = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("signup")

        if userSignedUp {
               // have to show another view
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("anyOtherViewThanSignUp") as! TViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController =  vc
        } else {
             // have to show SignUp view
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("signupView") as! SViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController =  vc

        }
    }
```