# Navigate view before loading base view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to navigate view controller conditionally. so before view controller load i need to check condition for navigate. I do same as below. also this is not my initial view else i can put condition in appDelegate.

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {
     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(false)
            if(!fileMgr.getCacheData(constants.defaultsKeys.KEY).isEqual("")){
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   let listing = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("listing") as! ListingController
                        self.showViewController(listing as UIViewController, sender: listing )
                    }
            }
     }
}
```

but it loads the base controller first then load listing controller. Any idea how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: check this answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289462/segue-in-swift-based-on-a-logic/31290593?noredirect=1#comment50573007_31290593

Comment: actually my initial view is different...and condition which i have given is different.